# Single table column having multiple foreign keys of other single table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a department table which has department_id as primary key.

I need to create teacher table in which a row can refer to two values in department_id

Department = `[("EC", "ELECTRONICS"), ("CS", "Computer Science")]`

Teacher = `("T001", "teacher1", ["CS", "EC"])`

Is it possible to create a table like this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to store 2 comma separated values in a single cell?

Comment: Sounds like you should use a 3rd table `TeacherDepartments` where you can store the `TeacherId` and `DepartmentId`.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yes

Comment: @sgeddes the additional value will be very sparse like multiple value may appear once in 100 rows

Comment: I'd still recommend using the 3rd table.  Storing a comma delimited list can be difficult for getting back to it's description...  If you really don't want the new table for some reason, you could add multiple `DepartmentId` columns to your `Teacher` table where the 2nd is `null` most of the time.  For example, `teacherid, name, departmentid, departmentid2`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Department (DeptCode [PK], Name):
>     EC, ELECTRONICS
>     CS, Computer Science
>
> Teacher (TeacherId [PK], Name, DeptList):
>     123, Teacher1, CS
>     234, Teacher2, EC
>     345, Teacher3, [CS, EC]
> ```

No.  What is possible in an Excel spreadsheet is not acceptable in a database table.  CSV in a single column is a gross error.  It breaks both First Normal Form and Second Normal Form (Dr E F Codd definitions):

1. **Each domain (attribute) must be Atomic wrt to the platform**
   meaning, each attribute must not be divisible.
2. **Each domain (attribute) must not be a set (repeating values)**

CSV is both divisible, *and* it is a set of repeating values.  If you break the rules, you will not have a database, that can be queried easily.  You will have a bucket of fish, that works sometimes.

Repeating values are stored in a subordinate table.  Here, it is an **Associative Table**, a subordinate of Department and Teacher.  The PK is a composite, which is standard fare in a Relational database.  Get used to it.  The table does not need yet another `id` field.

```
Department (DeptCode [PK], Name):
    EC, ELECTRONICS
    CS, Computer Science

Teacher (TeacherId [PK], Name):
    123, Teacher1
    234, Teacher2
    345, Teacher3

TeacherDepartment (TeacherId, DeptCode)
    PK (TeacherId, DeptCode):
    123, CS
    234, EC
    345, CS
    345, EC
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can create a table called teacher and have a varchar field which can store the department_details as a comma seperated string. It would be a wrong design from RDBMS point of view.

You would probably want to keep the relationship between a teacher and the department in another table.

```
+------------+---------------+
| teacher_id | department_id |
+------------+---------------+
|        100 | CS            |
|        100 | EC            |
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: here teacher_id is primary key so i cannot have multiple values for same teacher_id

Comment: This is a new table Teacher_Department table.

Comment: As the the data is sparse like multiple data appears once in 100 or 200 rows i do not want to separate out the relation from the teacher table itself

Comment: You asked for advice and have been given the best: create a third table. The fact that the condition occurs in only 1 in 100 rows means nothing at all - every query needs to assumes this case is that 1.  So to justify that table would require exactly 1 occurrence.  In the long run you will be glad you did it properly. You are free, however, to ignore that advice. But if so in the long run you will pay the price.